# 'Extensions' menu item is missing

Tags: extension, menu, system-settings

I run two installations of CiviCRM. Both on Wordpress. Both CiviCRM version 5.54.1, php version 8.1.1. Both on the same server.

Today I noticed that on one of the installations, the 'Extensions' menu item is missing from the Administer/System Settings menu. Where there should be a horizontal line separating Components and Extensions from the rest of the menu items, the line is also missing. Weird. The other installation doesn't have this problem.

Anyone any suggestions for where to start investigating? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why it might have disappeared, but you can add it back under Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Navigation Menu (the url is civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. 'Extensions' and the horizontal line had somehow escaped to the Customize Data and Screens menu, so I moved it back.